# How to link two activities in Android project

Tags: android

I just want to code for splashscreen. for that I used intent but I am getting error that instrumention source not found. I have two files `splashscreen.java` and `myapps.java` where I have use threading concept and called anothe activity as

```
finally
{
  finish();
  startActivity(new Intent("com.example.MyApps"));
  stop();
}
```

@ startAcitivy I am getting axception please guide me do I have to modify androidmanifest file? if yes please provide me syntax for that.

Comment: I don't find any use of calling stop(); after finish. I guess its trying to stop the thread. What thing you have been using your thread for? if possible, put up your manifest code here.

Comment: You don't need finish() or stop(). Starting a new activity will automatically manage putting away the current activity.

Comment: She needs to dispose the splash screen so that users doesn't see it when they hit back button while being on the MyApps activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting a new Activity with intent, I prefer using it like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyClass.this, MyApps.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and have proper entry on your manifest for your `MyApps` class like:

```
<application>
    .......
    .....
    <activity android:name="com.example.MyApps" />
    ........
</application>
```

Comment: This is the proper constructor to use for starting a specific intent class. I think the code in the original question is using the constructor that takes an intent type name such as ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: Maybe, but I feel her requirement is to start a particular activity once her Splash Screen finishes displaying some company logo n else.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<activity android:name="com.example.MyApps"></activity>
```

in your manifest.